# How do I create an Import File Button with Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

So you know how when you use Notepad (on Windows), for example, and you want to open an old file? You click file, then open, then a file dialog opens ups and you can select the file you want, and the program will display its contents.

Basically, I want to make a button in Python that can do that exact thing.

Here's my function for the button-

```
def UploadAction():
    #What to do when the Upload button is pressed
    from tkinter import filedialog
```

When I click on the button assigned to this action, nothing happens, no errors, no crash, just nothing.

Comment: SO is not a code completion tool. Please read [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read some documents on filedialog, I am sure they are out there..

Comment: Importing `filedialog` isn't enough. You also need to _call_ `filedialog.askopenfilename()` (or one of the other functions defined in the package).

Comment: Here's a little (Python 2) [documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/tkFileDialog.html) for the `tkFileDialog` module (which was renamed `tkinter.filedialog` in Python 3).

Comment: Are you saying that nowhere on the internet were you able to find any examples whatsoever of opening a file in tkinter?

Answer (score 35):

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog

def UploadAction(event=None):
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    print('Selected:', filename)

root = tk.Tk()
button = tk.Button(root, text='Open', command=UploadAction)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Good, nice, made me answer a question :-), 2000 rep got for you